# Are the cloning chambers reusable?

Tags: command-and-conquer-rivals

With the introduction of [cloning lab](https://www.ea.com/games/command-and-conquer/command-and-conquer-rivals/news/update-1-4#2), there is a new "Cloning Master Bundle" with the cost of 625 diamonds containing 5 **Standard** cloning chambers.

[image: Cloning Master Bundle]

[image: Cloning Master Bundle description]

Are these cloning chambers re-usable? Or is it just an "*use it once and then it is gone forever*" item?

Comment: I have tweeted them asking this, will see what they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cloning master bundle comes with 5x standard cloning chambers and each are one  time use only, see tweet confirming from official C&C: Rivals account below.

[image: A Tweet]

Comment: Thank you for sharing the tweet, it turns out that the bundle contains 5 "Standards Chambers" so all of them are one use only, I added the description screenshoot.